# Does a knot and a tunnel exterior having free fundamental group imply it's an unknotting tunnel?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

The title is just about it.  Assume we have a nontrivial knot $K$ in $S^3$ and the exterior of $K$, $E(K)$, is $S^3 \setminus N(K)$.  Here $N(K)$ is a regular neighborhood.

1. Let $\tau$ be a properly embedded arc in $E(K)$ and let $M = E(K)\setminus N(\tau)$.  Now, if we know that $\pi_1(M) = \langle x,y\vert \rangle$, does this necessarily mean that $\tau$ is an unknotting tunnel and the tunnel number of $K$ is one, $t(K)=1$?
2. I would like to know this in a more general setting, but the simplest case is all I really need for now. Given $T = \{\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_j\}$ properly embedded disjoint arcs, and $M = E(K)\setminus N(T)$ with $\pi_1(M) $ free, does that mean that $t(K) \leq j$?

I am a little confused by the statements of [Scharlemann and Thompson's Theorem 7.5](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214447220) (first page of the pdf) about embedded graphs, but think that they are working in a more restrictive setting.  But I could not find the answer to my question written down anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "yes".  This is because the manifold $M(K)$ is (in both cases) a handlebody of the correct genus.  To see this, you will need to apply the disk theorem several times. The end of the proof requires Alexander's theorem: the three-sphere is irreducible.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you know of a reference for this?

Comment: See Theorem 5.2 of Hempel's book "3-manifolds".  However, as I recall his plan of proof is a bit different from what I suggest above.

Answer (score 4):

Lemma 2.2 in the following paper contains the proof.

[Synchronism of an incompressible non-free Seifert surface for a knot and
an algebraically split closed incompressible surface in the knot complement](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-99-05068-6)

Comment: Ozawa-san and @SamNead  Thank you both!